# Charge Paypal users without letting them enter their password again

Tags: paypal, payment

We want to offer payments using paypal within our web-app concept. A few days ago i took my first ride using uber in Germany. They provide to add paypal as payment method and after every ride i just can pay using paypal without entering my credentials again.

How to implement a payment process like this?
We want our users to add paypal as payment method and then - *X days* aftersignup (eg. when we found the right product for him) we want to start the subscription.

The thing is that these *X days* varies from user to user so we cant use a billing agreement with a fixed start date and due to the fact its a subscription model we cant use just a single payment authorization.

Comment: @praveen posted the answer to my question in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12702017/787824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: Paypal calls this feature "Adaptive Payments". You can read it here: [Adaptive Payments API Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)